# OrderedCollection with Moveup And MoveDown

Tags: c#, .net

Is there any built-in Ordered Collection which support `Move-Up` and `Move-Down` of items ?

i wanna have Ordered Collection(could be List) where i can be sure that when i insert items it will be

inserted at the end of the Collection, then i want to be able to do something like this

```
Col.MoveUp(Item1);//Takes Item1 and move its index one step up.
                  //if its index is 3 it will be 2 and item on index 2 will be 3
Col.MoveDown(item2);
```

Comment: You mean exchange position with its neighbor?

Comment: Look at it side-ways.  You'll discover you can simply swap items.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is very easy to build up your own. Here I made them as extension methods. Another option is to define your own collection, inherit it from List and insert these methods there.

```
public static class ListExtensions
{
    public static void MoveUp<T>(this List<T> list, T item)
    {
        int index = list.IndexOf(item);

        if (index == -1)
        {
            // item is not in the list
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("item");
        }

        if (index == 0)
        {
            // item is on top
            return;
        }

        list.Swap(index, index - 1);
    }

    public static void MoveDown<T>(this List<T> list, T item)
    {
        int index = list.IndexOf(item);

        if (index == -1)
        {
            // item is not in the list
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("item");
        }

        if (index == list.Count - 1)
        {
            // item is no bottom
            return;
        }

        list.Swap(index, index + 1);
    }

    private static void Swap<T>(this List<T> list, int i1, int i2)
    {
        T temp = list[i1];
        list[i1] = list[i2];
        list[i2] = temp;
    }
}
```

Comment: I think swapping is faster than remove and insert operations because this will reallocate all items with index greater than the index of your item

Comment: @Miroprocessor, good observation, thanks. I've updated the post.

Answer (score 1):

The prefix 'Ordered' is usually used for sorted collections, you don't want that.

You can use a standard `List<>` and a few lines of code:

```
//untested
// Extension method, place in public static class.
public static void MoveDown(this IList<T> list, int index)  
{
   if (index >= list.Count) ... // error
   if (index > 0)
   {
       var temp = list[index];
       list.RemoveAt(index);
       list.Insert(index - 1, temp);
   }
}
```

And use it like

```
var data = new List<string>();
...
data.MoveDown(2);
```

This will Move the item from index 2 to index 1.
I just realized I used the reversed notion of up/down, it's a choice.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is anything built in like this, especially when the same could be done by simple swapping, taking into consideration the boundary cases.

You may want to implement your own Collection which extends one of the existing collections to add the desired methods.